# FastAPI pydantic model property in a JSON response

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

I want to use a property to automatically generate key-value pairs and include them in a FastAPI JSON Response.
In my example, I'm attempting to use a property within a Pydantic model, but it's not working as expected.

I requested: http://127.0.0.1:8000/
and expected to receive: `{"id": "my_name", "name": "My Name"}`
but I received: `{"id": "my_name"}`

Please help me find an elegant solution to properly document property in http://127.0.0.1:8000/docs and include the value in the response.

```py
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import Field, BaseModel

app = FastAPI()


class Item(BaseModel):
    id: str = Field(description="Item ID")
    # name: str = Field(description="Item name")  # NEED USE THIS ARGUMENT AS PROPERTY

    model_config = {
        "json_schema_extra": {
            "examples": [{"id": "my_name", "name": "My Name"}]
        }
    }

    @property
    def name(self) -> str:
        return self.id.replace("_", " ").upper()


@app.get("/")
async def main() -> Item:
    return Item(id="my_name")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `computed_field` decorator.

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, computed_field


class Item(BaseModel):
    id: str = Field(description="Item ID")

    @computed_field
    @property
    def name(self) -> str:
        return self.id.replace("_", " ").upper()
```

You can omit `@property` decorator for simplicity.

> If applied to functions not yet decorated with `@property` or `@cached_property`, the function is automatically wrapped with `property`

Ref: https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/api/fields/#pydantic.fields.computed_field